# Heroku Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (970485)

Tags: node.js, api, express, puppeteer

Actually am making an API for some works with puppeteer, it works in my local bcoz i had executable path

also in docs it says no need for set executable path but my error is

```
Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (970485).
```

My code For the launch() is

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            ],
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
```

Here i use Railway (Heroku clone)

If am right,
i have made mistakes in Executable path
lmk where i made the error
thank you

Comment: anyone? no one can find ans till now?

Comment: hello none of them can answer?